# MariaDB, UPDATE with SELECT, LIMIT in subquery

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to update a field in a table using a SELECT query, when I execute I see the errors:

```
08:10:16    UPDATE TABLE `Tesla-20240105` SET `state`=1 WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `Tesla-20240105` WHERE `state` IS NULL LIMIT 10)    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE `Tesla-20240105` SET `state`=1 WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `Tesla-2...' at line 1  0.00013 sec
08:10:48    UPDATE `Tesla-20240105` SET `state`=1 WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `Tesla-20240105` WHERE `state` IS NULL LIMIT 10)  Error Code: 1235. This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'    0.040 sec
```

The table can have potentially 300,000 records, the above is an attempt to select just 10 where the state is NULL and modify them, any suggestions on how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Does the table name `Tesla-20240105` mean that you have multiple identical tables?  That is [usually] a bad schema design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about moving `limit` out of subquery, into the main query?

```
UPDATE `Tesla-20240105` SET 
  `state`=1 
WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id` 
               FROM `Tesla-20240105` 
               WHERE `state` IS NULL
              ) 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thank you, thats excellent and so simple.

Comment: This is quite inefficient since it must find all the nulls, then use only 10 of them.  Go with sarh's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're updating the same table that you use to check the "id IN" condition, there is no need in IN subquery, you can do just "WHERE state IS NULL" in the main UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE `Tesla-20240105` 
  SET `state` = 1 
  WHERE `state` IS NULL
  LIMIT 10
```

That should allow to avoid the full execution of subquery, or in other words - to use LIMIT to avoid WHERE condition check for all records.

Here is the demo (just with lower number of records): https://dbfiddle.uk/4qvhSXZU

Comment: Be aware that, without `ORDER BY`, it will be picking an unpredictable 10.